# How do I add an "edittext" that when you type in a specific word an action happens

Tags: android, android-edittext

How do I add a "edittext" that when you type in a specific word such as "apple" it will make a new xml page pop up. But if the user types in a different word besides "apple" it will make a different xml page pop up.

What I'm trying to accomplish is somethings similar to a logo quiz game where when you type in the right word, a new thing pops up.

I have absolutely no idea how to do it. if u could show me a video on how to do it, that would be very helpful thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

You should use a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to watch for changes and do whatever you want on `afterTextChanged()`.

Comment: so using textwatcher i can add a secret word that if the user types performs an action