# How do I show a toast whenever the user enters a word?

Tags: android

I have a simple layout with an EditText and a Button. I want a toast to appear whenever the user enters a particular word in the EditText. How might I do that?

```
Button btn;
EditText edt;
String Event;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button1);
    edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    Event=new String(edt.getText().toString());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(Event.equals("Test")){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Great!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Your question is so simple that everybody can answer.. but if you show us what have you tried..Then we will provide you answer..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604595/how-do-i-add-an-edittext-that-when-you-type-in-a-specific-word-an-action-happe/15604686#15604686

Comment: Im a beginner guys so if you could show me an example it would be very helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `new String` from:

```
Event=new String(edt.getText().toString());
```

like this:

```
Event= edt.getText().toString();
```

and put all of this in the onClick of your button:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        Event = edt.getText().toString();
        if(Event.equals("Test"))
        {
           Toast.makeText(this, "Great!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `TextWatcher` to your `EditText`.

This tutorial shows you what you need to do: http://karanbalkar.com/2012/10/tutorial-11-using-textwatcher-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

```
   EditText e = (EditText)findViewById(..); 
   e.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

   @override
   void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
   {
        if(the word is in s.toString())
        {
         Toast...show();
        }
   }

   });
```